# python comparison for trees represented as tuples

Tags: python, tree, comparison, tuples

I'm representing trees with tuples. Say

```
t1=(t2,t3) and t4=(t5,t6)
```

Is it true that when comparing two such trees with `==`, it first tests if references `t2` and `t5` are equal then if references `t3` and `t6` are equal, if they are not equal then it tries to compare the actual contents of `t2` and `t5`, then the contents of `t3` and `t6` ?
**LE:**
The following code doesn't call `__eq__` it seems that my assumption is right, and that it doesn't evaluate the tuples recursively as I understand from the documentation.

```
class C:
  def __init__(self,a):
    self.a=a
  def __eq__(self,oth):
    print self.a,oth.a
    return oth.a==self.a

p=(C(1),C(2))
l=(p,p)
f=(p,p)
print l==f
```

On the other hand this code does call `__eq__`

```
   q=(C(1),C(2))
   p=(C(1),C(2))
   l=(q,q)
   f=(p,p)
   print l==f
```

Comment: What do you mean by *python trees*. How are you representing them as tuples?

Comment: [python] trees, should have left python only in the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, tuples attempt to short-circuit the comparison process so two tuples are equal if they are the same tuple or if their elements are either identical or equal.

In particular:

```
>>> nan = float('NaN')
>>> left = (nan, nan)
>>> right = (nan, nan)
>>> left==right
True
>>> left[0]==right[0]
False
```

which seems pretty broken.

Comment: @titus: Python always assumes that objects compare equal to themselves.  Objects failing to have this property will behave strange in all standard containers (see for example [NaNs as key in dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441857/nans-as-key-in-dictionaries)).  The IEEE standard prescribes that NaN must not compare equal to itself, so Python had to accept some weirdness here -- see the [discussion on this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue4296) in Python's bug tracker.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq):

> Sequence types also support
>   comparisons. In particular, tuples and
>   lists are compared lexicographically
>   by comparing corresponding elements.
>   This means that to compare equal,
>   every element must compare equal and
>   the two sequences must be of the same
>   type and have the same length.

Details about comparisons of the elements are also [documented](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Comment: The example wrote in the LE isn't covered by the documentation, I think it proves my assumption

Comment: @titus: That is because `l` and `f` are bound to the same tuple. Python does not need to call `__eq__` to know they are equal, because they are the same object. If you do `l=((C(1),C(2)), (C(1),C(2)))` (and the same for `r`), then `__eq__` will be called.

Comment: It wasn't obvious for me that it wouldn't recurse all the way. Now I know better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've done a little snippet of code to test your assumptions :

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value=value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "eq %s with %s"%(self, other)
        return other.value == self.value
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        print "cmp with %s"%other
        return cmp(other.value, self.value)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s(%s)"%(self.__class__.__name__, self.value)


t1 = (Foo(1), Foo(2))
t2 = (Foo(1), Foo(3))

print t1 == t2
```

that outputs :

```
eq Foo(1) with Foo(1)    # equality testing of first item of tuple t1/t2
eq Foo(2) with Foo(3)    # equality testing of second item of tuple t1/t2
False
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I extended it in the LE to prove my point. I think my assumption is right