# Pandas dataframe into sparse dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

How do I convert a pandas dataFrame into a *sparse* dictionary of dictionaries, where only the indexes of some cutoff are shown.  In the toy example below, I only want indexes for each column whose values > 0

```
import pandas as pd

table1 = [['gene_a', -1 , 1], ['gene_b', 1, 1],['gene_c', 0, -1]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(table)
df1.columns = ['gene','cell_1', 'cell_2']
df1 = df1.set_index('gene')
dfasdict = df1.to_dict(orient='dict')
```

This gives:

`dfasdict = {'cell_1': {'gene_a': -1, 'gene_b': 0, 'gene_c': 0}, 'cell_2': {'gene_a': 1, 'gene_b': -1, 'gene_c': -1}}`

But the desired output is a sparse dictionary, where only values less than zero are shown:

`desired = {'cell_1': {'gene_a': -1}, 'cell_2': {'gene_b': -1, 'gene_c': -1}}`

I can do some processing to change the `dfasdict` dictionary after creation, but I want to do the conversion in the same step since processing afterwards involves iterating over very large dictionaries.  Is this possible to do all within pandas?

Comment: [This](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html) should be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result uses a dictionary comprehension to generate the result.  For each column in `cell_1` and `cell_2`, it finds those that are less than (`lt`) zero and converts the result to a dictionary.

```
>>> {col: df1.loc[df1[col].lt(0), col].to_dict() for col in ['cell_1', 'cell_2']}
{'cell_1': {'gene_a': -1}, 'cell_2': {'gene_c': -1}}
```

To help understand what is going on here:

```
>>> df1.loc['cell_1'].lt(0)
gene
gene_a     True
gene_b    False
gene_c    False
Name: cell_1, dtype: bool

>>> df1.loc[df1['cell_1'].lt(0), 'cell_1'].to_dict()
{'gene_a': -1}
```

Comment: This works, but the `for` loop is making this really slow.  Is it possible to use masking and aggregation to find only the `True` values

Answer (score 1):

Delete last row of your code and add this one.

```
from pandas import compat

def to_dict_custom(data):
    return dict((k, v[v<0].to_dict()) for k, v in compat.iteritems(data))

dfasdict = to_dict_custom(df1)
print dfasdict
```

which yields,

```
{'cell_2': {'gene_c': -1.0}, 'cell_1': {'gene_a': -1.0}}
```

line 3&4 inspired by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033301/make-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dict-and-dropna) please check.