# How can I sum collection.Counter objects in a Python Pandas Dataframe using the update() method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, counter

I'm dealing with semi-structured data that doesn't fully fit into a pandas dataframe, so I have some columns containing collections.Counter objects (i.e. dictionaries) of vastly varying lengths.

I need to apply a groupby on another column and need to sum up these Counters, however without dropping zeros or ignoring negative values. That means I can not use the sum() method on these columns.

The method of choice would be the update() method, however it can't be simply applied like the sum() method as it needs an argument which would be another Counter which however sits in another row and not another column.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import collections as cc

A = [cc.Counter({'A': 1,'B':-1,'C': 1}),\
     cc.Counter({'A':-1,'B': 1,       'D': 0,'E': 1}),\
     cc.Counter({'A': 0,                     'E': 0,'F': 1}),\
     cc.Counter({       'B': 0,'C':-1,       'E':-1,'F':-1})]

B = ['N','N','N','N']

S1 = pd.Series(B,index=['W','X','Y','Z'],name='K',dtype=str)
S2 = pd.Series(A,index=['W','X','Y','Z'],name='L',dtype=dict)
F = pd.merge(S1.to_frame(),S2.to_frame(),left_index=True,right_index=True)
print F
```

This leads to the output

```
   K                                        L
W  N             {u'A': 1, u'C': 1, u'B': -1}
X  N    {u'A': -1, u'B': 1, u'E': 1, u'D': 0}
Y  N              {u'A': 0, u'E': 0, u'F': 1}
Z  N  {u'C': -1, u'B': 0, u'E': -1, u'F': -1}
```

Doing this:

```
G = F.groupby('K')
print G.sum()
```

Leads to this output:

```
    L
K    
N  {}
```

But what I want is this:

```
Counter({'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'B': 0, 'E': 0, 'D': 0, 'F': 0})
```

which can be manually done with the update method like this:

```
for i in range(1,4):
  A[0].update(A[i])
print A[0]
```

So I either need a technique to apply update() to a groupby object either by creating an appropriate function or by changing the grouped rows into columns (something that seems rather inefficient and time-consuming to do), or I will have to restructure my data in a way that omits zeros and negative values in the Counters.

Any ideas are welcome.

EDIT:
I still fail to apply the proposed solution to the grouped DataFrame in my example:

```
G.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x).sum().to_dict())
```

gives the result:

```
K
N    {u'K': u'NNNN', u'L': {}}
dtype: object
```

The problem is that I don't quite understand how apply on groupby objects works.

Like when I'm doing this:

```
F.groupby('K').apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

The result is:

```
K
N    [K, L]
dtype: object
```

And I don't understand why and how.

EDIT 2 (SOLUTION):

After @piRSquared answers helped me to solve the problem I'm adding the full solution to not only get the dictionary but to get the dictionary back into a DataFrame as well:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict([to_dict_dropna(pd.concat([F.K, F.L.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)\
.groupby('K').sum())]).T.reset_index()
```

The function to_dict_dropna() is taken from "[make pandas DataFrame to a dict and dropna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033301)" and neccessary if there keys without values in the summed dictionaries.
I'm transposing the frame and resetting the index because I need the initial index as a column. Then I merge this with other frames to get the final format I need.

PS: This method is extremely memory-consuming and should not be used to larger datasets.

Comment: shouldn't the final value for `'C'` be `-1`?  As well as for `'E'` and `'F'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the list of dicts `A`

```
A = [{'A': 1,'B':-1,'C': 1},
     {'A':-1,'B': 1,       'D': 0,'E': 1},
     {'A': 0,                     'E': 0,'F': 1},
     {       'B': 0,'C':-1,       'E':-1,'F':-1}]


pd.DataFrame(A).stack().groupby(level=1).sum().to_dict()

{'A{'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'E': 0.0, 'F': 0.0}
```

---

I'll keep that original answer alone.  But it was based on my incorrect assumption that you wanted the last value.  The answer then evolved when I realized `sum` is what you needed.

Given that, this is a better solution

```
pd.DataFrame(A).sum().to_dict()
```

To apply this directly to the dataframe `F` you've defined:

```
pd.concat([F.K, F.L.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).groupby('K').sum()
```

[image]

Comment: This takes the last value of each dict and puts them together, but I need the sum of all values with the same key regardless of them being 0 or negative. 1 + (-1) should yield 0, not -1. But I will look into the stack method more closely, I haven't been aware of that before.

Comment: @Khris Ah, now I've got it.

Comment: Actually you got very close to the answer, I just needed one adjustment: pd.DataFrame(A).stack().groupby(level=1).sum().to_dict() - EDIT: And you were a bit faster than me, thanks for solving it so easily.

Comment: @piRSquared - very nice last solution  ;)

Comment: @piRSquared: I'm still having issues with applying your solution properly to the whole DataFrame, see my Edits in my question.

Comment: @piRSquared: It did, I just had to make one modification:  pd.concat([F.K,F.L.apply(pd.Series)],axis=1).groupby('K').sum().loc['N'].to_dict()

Comment: @piRSquared: I managed to get the whole thing working with the real data omitting the iloc-part and using an enhanced to_dict function to drop NaN values (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033301/make-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dict-and-dropna ). What remains is the fact that this solution spreads the dictionaries into a full dataframe which in my real case leads to a huge sparsely populated data frame with around 10000 columns and millions of rows on which the groupby and the summation happen. I only need to do this once though, so it should work out. Thanks again.