# How to merge 2 list of dict

Tags: python

I have 2 list of dict and i want to merge the 2 list of dict based on the key with same value

for example

```
dict1 = [{'date_time': '2020-10-11 10:00', 'value': 10},{'date_time': '2020-10-11 11:00', 'value': 20},{'date_time': '2020-10-11 12:00', 'value': 30}]

dict2 = [{'date_time': '2020-10-11 13:00', 'value2': 10},{'date_time': '2020-10-11 11:00', 'value2': 30},{'date_time': '2020-10-11 12:00', 'value2': 20}]

resultant_dict = [{'date_time': '2020-10-11 13:00', 'value2': 10},{'date_time': '2020-10-11 11:00', 'value2': 30, 'value': 20},{'date_time': '2020-10-11 12:00', 'value2': 20, 'value': 30}, {'date_time': '2020-10-11 10:00', 'value': 10}]
```

Comment: can you please share us some code you tried?

Comment: dict1_list = {d['date_time']: d for d in dict1}
for d in dict2:
      dict1_list .setdefault(d['date_time'], dict()).update(d)

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65564396/edit) and share your code there

Comment: Are `value` and `value2` custom classes or did you forget the quotation marks?

Comment: I forgot  to put the quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

A simple & efficient method is to use Pandas.

```
def merge(lst1, lst2):
    # Convert list of dictionaries to dataframes
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(lst2)

    # Use Merge to place common keys together based upon time (outer merge)
    df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date_time', how='outer')

    # Using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033301/make-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dict-and-dropna
    # Convert Dataframe to dictionary list dropping NAN column values in DataFrame
    return [ v.dropna().to_dict() for k,v in df.iterrows() ]
```

**Usage**

```
print(merge(dict1, dict2))
# Output
[{'date_time': '2020-10-11 10:00', 'value': 10.0},
 {'date_time': '2020-10-11 11:00', 'value': 20.0, 'value2': 30.0},
 {'date_time': '2020-10-11 12:00', 'value': 30.0, 'value2': 20.0},
 {'date_time': '2020-10-11 13:00', 'value2': 10.0}]
```