# Skip nan values when reading excel as dict using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary, nan

I have an excel table with a sheet whose content is as follows:

```
A     B        C        D       
1     039#     AA8      MA21   
2     088#              MA22   
3     077#              MA23      
4                       MA24   
5
```

I can correctly read the table as follows:

```
>>> df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_path)
>>> df      
       A     B    C     D
    0  1  039#  AA8  MA21
    1  2  088#  nan  MA22
    2  3  077#  nan  MA23
    3  4   nan  nan  MA24
    4  5   nan  nan   nan
```

What I really want is to convert this table into a dictionary of lists where each list contains only the values ​​from cells filled in the excel sheet, however, when using the `to_dict` method, what I get is a list for each column with values unwanted `nan`:

```
>>> df.to_dict('list')
    {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'B': ['039#', '088#', '077#', 'nan', 'nan'],
     'C': ['AA8', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
     'D': ['MA21', 'MA22', 'MA23', 'MA24', 'nan']}
```

What I want to get is the following:

```
>>> df.to_dict('list')
    {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'B': ['039#', '088#', '077#'],
     'C': ['AA8'],
     'D': ['MA21', 'MA22', 'MA23', 'MA24']}
```

Of course once I get the dict I could iterate through each list filtering out the `nan` values, however I would like to know if there is a better approach that is closer to the example above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make pandas DataFrame to a dict and dropna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033301/make-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dict-and-dropna)

Comment: @Chris I had already seen that answer, however the solutions provided in all answers involve "manual" iteration. I would like to know if there is a more "direct" approach, however, if it is not possible, I will indeed mark the one you indicated as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currently in an appropriate place to do a test, but if the need arises, be quick. You are trying to change to dict, but pandas it works by indexing, so when you perform the excel reading, it transforms into dataframe of rows and columns, the values that don't exist will be replaced by nan, when you transform that to dict, the The function is not performing wrong, it will work according to the number of lines, keeping the nans, for you to remove it, you will have to manually access the dictionary and somehow manipulate your list to drop the missing values. Sorry if I can't send a function to help right now.

Comment: Don't worry, I already have a function that performs the task, I just wanted to know if it could be done "directly"

Comment: Per the documentation [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) doesn't say anything about it, more a separate handling issue, you can loop through the list and make a new append so that it removes. If you don't care so much about the availability of data

Answer (score 0):

you can mask `NaN`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_path)
df = df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna(how='all')
df.to_dict('list')
```

or else if you just want to ignore. [Ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#:%7E:text=Read%20an%20Excel%20file%20into,or%20a%20list%20of%20sheets.) check all options here

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel(xlsxpath,na_filter=False)

df.to_dict('list')
```