# Pandas: sparse dataframe to dictionary without nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large sparse dataframe `sdf` contains mainly `NaN` in it. When I use `sdf.to_dict()` it outputs a dense version of that matrix with all `null` values filled. How could I omit those `NaN` entries and only output entries do have value into the dict?

For example, `sdf` is:

```
          2018-02-02  2018-02-03
23:58:36         NaN         NaN
23:58:37         1.0         NaN
23:58:40         NaN         NaN
23:58:41         NaN         NaN
23:58:42         NaN         NaN
23:58:43         NaN         NaN
23:58:48         NaN         NaN
23:58:49         NaN         NaN
23:58:50         NaN         NaN
23:58:52         NaN         1.0
23:58:59         NaN         NaN
23:59:00         NaN         NaN
23:59:01         NaN         NaN
23:59:05         NaN         NaN
23:59:07         NaN         NaN
```

`stf.to_dict()` would give:

```
{'2018-02-02': {'23:58:36': nan, '23:58:37': 1.0, '23:58:40':
  nan, '23:58:41': nan, '23:58:42': nan, '23:58:43': nan,
  '23:58:48': nan, '23:58:49': nan, '23:58:50': nan, '23:58:52':
  nan, '23:58:59': nan, '23:59:00': nan, '23:59:01': nan,
  '23:59:05': nan, '23:59:07': nan}, '2018-02-03': {'23:58:36':
  nan, '23:58:37': nan, '23:58:40': nan, '23:58:41': nan,
  '23:58:42': nan, '23:58:43': nan, '23:58:48': nan, '23:58:49':
  nan, '23:58:50': nan, '23:58:52': 1.0, '23:58:59': nan,
  '23:59:00': nan, '23:59:01': nan, '23:59:05': nan, '23:59:07':
  nan}}
```

Even `sdf` is a sparse dataframe.

---

Sorry for ambiguous. I want to keep all non `NaN` entries. The desired output is

```
{'2018-02-02': {'23:58:37': 1.0}, '2018-02-03': {'23:58:52': 1.0}}
```

Comment: Are you trying to drop `NaN` rows and convert into dict. `sdf.dropna(how='all').to_dict()`?

Comment: @SaiKumar Please see my update:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `dict comprehension`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for (k1, k2), v in df.stack().items():
    d[k2][k1] = v

d1 = dict(d)
```

If input is `Series` with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print (s)
2018-02-02 23:58:37    1.0
2018-02-03 23:58:52    1.0
dtype: float64

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in df.stack().items():
    d[k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')][k.strftime('%H:%M:%S')] = v

d1 = dict(d)
```

Comment: @LukasThaler - Thank you, solution was changed.

Answer (score 1):

An adaptation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24068482/10293548) answer will do exactly what you want

```
from math import isnan

sdd = sdf.dropna(how = 'all').to_dict()
clean_dict = {k: {j: sdd[k][j] for j in sdd[k] if not isnan(sdd[k][j])} for k in sdd}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, for me this is was the best aproach.

```
from pandas import isnull

[{k:i for k, i in row.iteritems() if not isnull(i)} for c, row in df.iterrows()]
```