# Remove keys from a dictionary which has "nan" values

Tags: python

I have source dictionary, please refer sample below. It has deep level nested sub-dictionaries and lists, and I need to remove all keys where the value is "nan".

```
data = {"col1":"val1","col2":"val2","col3":"val3","col4":"val3","list1":[{"l1":"v1","l2":"nan"},{"K1":"Kv1","K2":"nan"},{"M1":"Mv1","M2":"nan","sublist1":[{"SL1":"SV1","SL2":"nan"}]}],"list2":[{"l1":"v1","l2":"nan"},{"K1":"Kv1","K2":"nan"},{"M1":"Mv1","M2":"nan","sublist2":[{"SL1":"SV1","SL2":"nan"}]}]}
```

I tried following code by creating a function but it is not working as expected:

```
def cleanNullTerms(d): 
   clean = {}
   for k, v in d.items():
      if isinstance(v, list):
         for values in v:
            nested = cleanNullTerms(values)
            if values =='nan':
                clean[k] = nested
      elif v is not 'nan':
         clean[k] = v
   return clean
```

Comment: What does " it is not working as expected" mean? what does it do?

Comment: Please check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068306/is-there-a-way-to-remove-nan-from-a-dictionary-filled-with-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068306/is-there-a-way-to-remove-nan-from-a-dictionary-filled-with-data)

Comment: @HimanshuSharma OP *appears* to be working with strings, `"nan"` not `float('nan')`, although, that seems strange...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to remove nan from a dictionary filled with data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068306/is-there-a-way-to-remove-nan-from-a-dictionary-filled-with-data)

Answer (score 0):

Your code put values of list to the place that the list had. If there were many values every value overwrote last one so only last one got saved. And it did not go recusively into dictionaries. It still only removes "nan"s if they are nested with dicts and lists. For example it does not go into sets. If you want it to go into sets, write a comment and I can add this.

```
def cleanNullTerms(d):
   clean={}
   for k, v in d.items():
      if isinstance(v, list):
         v2=[]
         for value0 in v:
            nested=cleanNullTerms(value0)
            if value0!='nan':
                v2.append(nested)
         clean[k]=v2
      elif isinstance(v, dict):
          clean[k]=cleanNullTerms(v)
      elif v!='nan':
         clean[k]=v
   return clean
```

Answer (score 0):

You've didn't describe exactly what's wrong, but from inspection your function clearly looks wrong to me because it doesn't check for nested `dict`s. You also haven't indicated what your expected output would be, but the following looks correct to me.

```
from pprint import pprint, pp


def cleanNullTerms(d):
    clean = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            clean[k] = cleanNullTerms(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            clean[k] = [cleanNullTerms(values) for values in v]
        elif v != 'nan':
            clean[k] = v
    return clean


data = {'col1': 'val1',
        'col2': 'val2',
        'col3': 'val3',
        'col4': 'val3',
        'list1': [{'l1': 'v1', 'l2': 'nan'},
                  {'K1': 'Kv1', 'K2': 'nan'},
                  {'M1': 'Mv1',
                   'M2': 'nan',
                   'sublist1': [{'SL1': 'SV1', 'SL2': 'nan'}]}],
        'list2': [{'l1': 'v1', 'l2': 'nan'},
                  {'K1': 'Kv1', 'K2': 'nan'},
                  {'M1': 'Mv1',
                   'M2': 'nan',
                   'sublist2': [{'SL1': 'SV1', 'SL2': 'nan'}]}]}

data = cleanNullTerms(data)
pprint(data, sort_dicts=False)
```

Results printed:

```
{'col1': 'val1',
 'col2': 'val2',
 'col3': 'val3',
 'col4': 'val3',
 'list1': [{'l1': 'v1'},
           {'K1': 'Kv1'},
           {'M1': 'Mv1', 'sublist1': [{'SL1': 'SV1'}]}],
 'list2': [{'l1': 'v1'},
           {'K1': 'Kv1'},
           {'M1': 'Mv1', 'sublist2': [{'SL1': 'SV1'}]}]}
```