# Does comparing using `==` compare identities before comparing values?

Tags: python, identity, equality-operator

If I compare two variables using `==`, does Python compare the identities, and, if they're not the same, then compare the values?

For example, I have two strings which point to the same string object:

```
>>> a = 'a sequence of chars'
>>> b = a
```

Does this compare the values, or just the ids?:

```
>>> b == a
True
```

It would make sense to compare identity first, and I guess that is the case, but I haven't yet found anything in the documentation to support this. The closest I've got is [this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__):

> `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`

which doesn't tell me whether anything is done before calling `x.__eq__(y)`.

Comment: Python *falls back* to equality - if `__eq__` isn't defined, `a == b` is evaluated as `a is b`, to ensure that the comparison always has a result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's what I expected. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually, no that isn't what I expected. If `__eq__` is defined will it not check `id` first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For user-defined class instances, `is` is used as a fallback - where the default `__eq__` isn't overridden, `a == b` is evaluated as `a is b`. This ensures that the comparison will always have a result (except in the `NotImplemented` case, where comparison is explicitly forbidden).

This is (somewhat obliquely - good spot [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)) referred to in the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) (emphasis mine):

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by
>   default; with them, **all objects compare unequal (except with
>   themselves)** and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such
>   that `x == y` implies both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

---

You can demonstrate it as follows:

```
>>> class Unequal(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False


>>> ue = Unequal()
>>> ue is ue
True
>>> ue == ue
False
```

so `__eq__` must be called before `id`, but:

```
>>> class NoEqual(object):
    pass

>>> ne = NoEqual()
>>> ne is ne
True
>>> ne == ne
True
```

so `id` must be invoked where `__eq__` isn't defined.

---

You can see this [in the CPython implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c#l679), which notes:

```c
/* If neither object implements it, provide a sensible default
   for == and !=, but raise an exception for ordering. */
```

The *"sensible default"* implemented is a C-level equality comparison of the pointers `v` and `w`, which will return whether or not they point to the same object.

Comment: So, if we are implementing `__eq__`, and it makes sense, should we first check `id`?

Comment: @PeterWood you could do that, yes - where the comparison is complex, it would certainly be more efficient

Comment: @jonrsharpe The Cpython line explains that!

Comment: I checked the code for strings. Python [checks `is` first](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l10943). Many thanks for the direction.

Comment: @PeterWood no problem - you'll probably find that the other built-in types implement that too, where appropriate.

Comment: [Python 2.7](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l768) also falls back to pointer comparison, nice find.

Comment: Falling back to object identity for user-defined classes isn't a CPython implementation detail.  It's part of the language specification, but documented in [a slightly unexpected place](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Comment: @SvenMarnach aha! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by @jonrsharpe: *if* the objects being compared implement `__eq__`, it would be *wrong* for Python to check for identity first.

Look at the following example:

```
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> x is x 
True
>>> x == x
False
```

NaN is a specific thing that should never compare equal to itself; however, even in this case `x is x` should return `True`, because of the semantics of `is`.

Comment: Well, yeah, NaN is kind of an exception.  There are many cases where Python actually _does_ assume that object identity implies equality.  These cases often result in unexpected behaviour for `float('nan')`, like using [NaN as a dictionary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441857/nans-as-key-in-dictionaries) or checking `float('nan') in list_of_floats` (the latter will only yield `True` if the exact `float('nan')` object you are checking for is in the list, not any NaN).  So arguing that it would be "wrong" for Python to check for identity first seems a bit off.