# KeyError: nan in dict

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I do as below

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 0, 1, np.nan, 2, 0]})
mapper = {2.0: 0.0, 1.0: 1.0 ,0.0: 2.0, nan : nan}
df['a'] = [ mapper[x] for x in df['a'] ]
```

and

```
KeyError: nan
```

I tried to change dtypes

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(object)
```

but again

```
KeyError: nan
```

what's wrong?

Comment: For completeness, see question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441857/nans-as-key-in-dictionaries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@shx2 explains why this happens. But you can still do what you want — just forget the `NaN` and use `Series.map`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 0, 1, np.nan, 2, 0]})
mapper = {2.0: 0.0, 1.0: 1.0 ,0.0: 2.0}
df['a'] = df['a'].map(mapper)
print(df)

#      a
# 0  1.0
# 1  0.0
# 2  2.0
# 3  1.0
# 4  NaN
# 5  0.0
# 6  2.0
```

If you want to map the `NaN` entries to, say, `55`, use `.fillna()`:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(55)
print(df)

#       a
# 0   1.0
# 1   0.0
# 2   2.0
# 3   1.0
# 4  55.0
# 5   0.0
# 6   2.0
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that nan is "not a number", and as such it equals no other number, not even another nan. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

To demonstrate:

```
from numpy import nan
nan == nan
=> False
```

From this it must follow that nan is not in your dict, because it doesn't equal any of the keys.

Comment: Actually, Python first checks for reference equality when looking up a dict key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441857/nans-as-key-in-dictionaries

Comment: Interesting: `mapper[np.nan]` returns `nan` but `[mapper[x] for x in df['a']]` throws a `KeyError: nan`.

Comment: `df['a'][4] is np.nan` is `False`: it seems pandas is not returning `np.nan`, but just a `float('nan')`.