# weird hashable object behavior with null tuples in Python 3.6 dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the course of using the Pandas library, I have encountered unexpected behavior in Python dicts. I'm currently using CPython 3.6.4, the Python3 implementation installed from Brew. I'm currently on OSX 10.13 and in a virtualenvironment, although those details might be less relevant.

Step by step, I first created a lambda function that initializes a 3-tuple of NaNs.

```
In [1]: null_generator = lambda: (float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'))
```

Intuitively, the hashes of two different objects created using the same function should be the same...

```
In [2]: hash(null_generator())
Out[2]: 1267304713960822739

In [3]: hash(null_generator())
Out[3]: 1267304713960822739
```

...and yet they end up having unique hashes within a dict.

```
In [4]: python_dict = {}

In [5]: python_dict[null_generator()] = 0

In [6]: python_dict[null_generator()] = 1

In [7]: python_dict
Out[7]: {(nan, nan, nan): 0, (nan, nan, nan): 1}
```

This seems like a bug in the language implementation, but I'm wary of saying so without reading the language specification -- does anyone have input either a) validating the strangeness of this behavior or b) that can correct the conception of hashability and uniqueness that I have for Python objects?

Comment: It's because NaN doesn't compare equal to itself. Try `float('nan') == float('nan')`.

Comment: This behavior is the same in Python 2.7

Comment: For the same reason `hash(-1) == hash(-2)` yet `{-2:0, -1:1}`...

Comment: Dupe/closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441857/nans-as-key-in-dictionaries (3.6 changed dicts for `nan`, but not tuples containing `nan`)