# How to remove float('nan') node from a graph in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a dataset(pickle format) containing `float('nan')`, and I need to remove it.

It is possible to add `float('nan')` to a graph as a node in networkx. However, I don't know how to remove it.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(float('nan'))
print(G.nodes) # [nan], so there is float('nan') in the graph
G.remove_node(float('nan')) # this statement raise a NetworkxError showing nan not in the graph
```

Code and data in [CoReRank-WSDM-2019](https://github.com/LCS2-IIITD/CoReRank-WSDM-2019) and [BirdNest](https://bhooi.github.io/code/birdnest.zip).

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: NaN is not equal to NaN. You can use `math.isnan()` to see if a number is NaN, but I don't know if there is a convenient way to do that in networkx without manually looping over all nodes and checking their values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can test this on a simple dictionary, which is the underlying data structure of a NetworkX graph. Say you have:

```
d = {'a':3, float('nan'):4}
```

If we try accessing the `NaN` key, as you're trying to do:

```
d[float('nan')]
> KeyError: nan
```

The core cause of this, is explained by the fact that a `NaN` does not equal to itself:

```
>>> float("nan") == float("nan")
False
```

The reason behind why this causes the lookup to fail, is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441857/nans-as-key-in-dictionaries).

A workaround, could be to loop over the graph keys, and identify the `NaN` node and *then* remove that key using the same reference of the object:

```
import math

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(float('nan'))
G.add_node(3)
print(G.nodes) 
# [nan, 3]

nan_nodes = []
for node in G.nodes():
    if math.isnan(node):
        nan_nodes.append(node)
G.remove_nodes_from(nan_nodes)

G.nodes()
# NodeView((3,))
```

Comment: I see. I shall find all the NaN nodes and save their references. Then I can call `G.remove_nodes_from()` to delete them.

Comment: You can only have one node with the same node. Is that not the same with Nan nodes? @zxx the above loop removed them all from the graph btw