# Why can't a pandas dataframe value of NaN be used as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, pandas, hashtable, nan

I'm trying to use the elements of the `values` column in the below data frame as keys in a dictionary.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: rng = pd.date_range('2021-06-01', periods=4)
   ...: values = [1, -1, 0, np.nan]
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=rng, columns=['values'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
            values
2021-06-01     1.0
2021-06-02    -1.0
2021-06-03     0.0
2021-06-04     NaN
```

The goal is to map the elements of the `values` column to a set of new values in a separate column to produce the below data frame:

```
            values new_values
2021-06-01     1.0    A
2021-06-02    -1.0    B
2021-06-03     0.0    C
2021-06-04     NaN    D
```

So I created a dictionary with the keys as the elements in the `values` column.

```
In [3]: repl = {1: 'A', 0: 'B', -1: 'C',np.nan: 'D'}
In [4]: df['rule'] = df['Val'].apply(lambda x: repl[x])
```

'NaN', however, is creating a key error (despite it being hashable).

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-2e9d3caa7f9c> in <module>
----> 1 df['rule'] = df['Val'].apply(lambda x: repl[x])

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/PyAlgo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-143-2e9d3caa7f9c> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df['rule'] = df['Val'].apply(lambda x: repl[x])

KeyError: nan
```

Obviously, I can create the column manually for this simple example. However, this is just a minimally re-produceable example. In reality, I have a much larger data frame with many more potential keys.

Two questions:

1. why does 'NaN' generate a key error despite it being hashable?
2. what is the best way to solve this? One possibility is to set 'NaN' values to another value like -999 in the original data frame?

Comment: `np.nan` can certainly be used as a dict key.  You can try it yourself to prove that.  The complaint is not that `np.nan` is not hashable, it's that the key does not exist.  Is it possible you're actually getting the string "nan"?  Pandas does a lot of automatic conversions.

Comment: np.nan is indeed hashable as evidenced by the below.

Comment: In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: hash(np.nan)
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: d = {-1: 'A', np.nan: 'B'}

In [4]: d[np.nan]
Out[4]: 'B'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df["column"].map(dict)`

```
>>> df["new_values"] = df["values"].map(repl)
>>> df
            values new_values
2021-06-01     1.0          A
2021-06-02    -1.0          C
2021-06-03     0.0          B
2021-06-04     NaN          D
```

Comment: Many, thanks.  Do you know why 'NaN' cannot be used as a dictionary key once it's encapsulated as a value inside a pandas data frame?

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure what is going on here, could be some internals of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the explanation has to do with the fact that the way that python determines if a key is in a dictionary is 1. hashing the key and checking it against dictionary and then 2. checking to make sure that the key it is looking for `is` the key that it found in the dictionary.

The problem is that although `np.nan is np.nan` returns `True`, `np.float64(np.nan) is np.float(np.nan)` returns `False`. Similarly, `np.float64(np.nan) is np.nan` returns `False`.

My guess is that the reason your `apply` function does not work is that the lambda function you create is trying to find `np.float64(np.nan)` (or something similar from your DataFrame) in the dictionary `repl` and not finding it. Even if your original data just contained `np.nan`, it seems like pandas converts it to `numpy.float64` type.

E.g.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 0], [1,1]])
a[0][0], type(a[0][0]), type(np.nan)
>> nan, numpy.float64, float
```

`map` on the other hand takes a dictionary as an argument and is specifically designed to handle the case where some values are missing or equal to `np.nan` ( see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

For more on using `nan` as keys in dictionaries see this question: [NaNs as key in dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441857/nans-as-key-in-dictionaries)